# Concrete5: How to access external asp.net database?

Tags: database-connection, concrete5

I am working on a project where I need to access external database (asp.net) for some content and display the content on Concrete5. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

concrete5 uses the ADOdb php library. I'm assuming your asp.net application uses mssql.

http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#connect_ex

Scroll down a bit and you will get to the mssql part.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to connect to the database? Or how to take that data and display it on your concrete5 site?

Connecting to the database has nothing to do with concrete5 -- instead just google for "connect to SQL Server database from PHP" (or use ADODB as @mkly points out in his answer).

But if you are asking how to display the content, then the easiest way to do that is by creating a single_page -- see http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/pages/single-pages